# Rails dependencies issue when in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, production

Im working on a legacy oracle database with a slightly odd table naming convention where each column name is prefixed with the tables initial letters - eg policy.poli_id.

To make this database easier to work with I have a method  set_column_prefix  that creates accessors for each column with the prefix removed. ie:

```
# Taken from wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/howtouselegacyschemas
class << ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_column_prefix(prefix)
    column_names.each do |name|
      next if name == primary_key

      if name[/#{prefix}(.*)/e]
        a = $1

        define_method(a.to_sym) do
          read_attribute(name)
        end

        define_method("#{a}=".to_sym) do |value|
          write_attribute(name, value)
        end

        define_method("#{a}?".to_sym) do
          self.send("#{name}?".to_sym)
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is in a file (insoft.rb) in my lib/ directory, and required from from my config/environment.rb after the Rails::Initializer.run block.

This has been working fine in development, but when I try to run the application in production mode, I get the following error in all of my models:

```
dgs@dgs-laptop:~/code/voyager$ RAILS_ENV=production script/server 
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1964:in `method_missing': 
undefined method `set_column_prefix' for #<Class:0xb3fb81d8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/dgs/code/voyager/app/models/agent.rb:16
```

This error is triggered by the 'config.cache_classes = true' line in config/environments/production.rb.
If I set this to *false*, then rails will start up, but won't be caching classes. I'm guessing this makes rails cache all the models before it runs the Initializer block

If I move the 'require "insoft.rb'" to before the start of the Rails::Initializer.run block, then I get errors because ActiveRecord  hasn't been initialized yet:

```
usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
    from /home/dgs/code/voyager/lib/insoft.rb:1
```

Where should I be including this custom lib and set_column_prefix method in order for it to be picked up before the models are cached, but after all the activerecord files have loaded?

Cheers

Dave Smylie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should I be including this custom lib and set_column_prefix method in order for it to be picked up before the models are cached, but after all the activerecord files have loaded?

Try setting up an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializers). You can call it config/initializers/insoft.rb with the contents of your monkey patch:

```
class << ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_column_prefix(prefix)
    column_names.each do |name|
      next if name == primary_key

      if name[/#{prefix}(.*)/e]
        a = $1

        define_method(a.to_sym) do
          read_attribute(name)
        end

        define_method("#{a}=".to_sym) do |value|
          write_attribute(name, value)
        end

        define_method("#{a}?".to_sym) do
          self.send("#{name}?".to_sym)
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks guys. That seems to have fixed the problem.